# Is it also possible to graduate labels like it is possible for markers?

Tags: qgis, vector, labeling, symbology

QGIS Dufour provides an enhanced vector-styling interface but is it also possible to graduate the labels like it is possible for the markers?

I have cities with population data: I can have the marker size according to the population value but is it also possible to adjust the lettersize of the label according the population?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can.  Just set a field or expression for the label size property:

[image]